# Orientation of repeating data in slickgrid

Tags: slickgrid

Does anyone know whether it is possible to change the orientation of slickgrid so that the repeating data is displayed horizontally rather than vertically? What I mean by this is that the column headers are shown to the left and the data goes across instead of a standard table.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've used SlickGrid quite a bit and I'm petty sure this is not possible. This would be a fundamental change to the way SlickGrid works and prohibitively complex I suspect.

SlickGrid works by virtualising the rows to be displayed and only rendering those rows which are visible in the current viewport, rendering each row as a DIV. It can do this because a DIV renders across the page as a row and it knows exactly how high a single row is. Using DIV elements to render columns left-to-right would require a very different approach using DIV floats, if possible at all.

So sorry, but I think the answer is no. Unless someone here has other experience and can correct me.

Comment: That was my suspicion to be honest but I was hoping I was wrong. I'll have to use something else.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that delegating data-understanding tasks to a component that is just supposed to be a *view* respects separation of concerns.

I, for one, would send unique data (which of course requires some processing from your business layer) to a SlickGrid. Then I'd send the duplicated data to either a second SlickGrid, or to a custom component.